# Is it possible to export/import a virtual box machine in one file?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a Vagrant set up with 3 virtual machines. Each machine has its own shell script for provisioning.

Now I would like to share the exact same status of my set up with somebody else.  Since the provisioning procedure takes really (!!) long for each machine, I hope there is another solution.

Ideally I would be able to save each machine as it is in one file, which the other person then could import into Virtualbox. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you would like to make a Vagrant base box from provisioned by Vagrant VMs. This is not recommended way to go. How you can approach this is:

1. Create new VM manually with required OS in the VBox.
2. Adjust it so Vagrant can connect to it as described [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes/base.html) and [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/boxes.html).
3. Provision it using your shell scripts.
4. Install all the things you would find useful to have on this VM.
5. Use Vagrant to package it as a base box as described [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/boxes.html).

After packaging it with Vagrant you will get a Vagrant base box file with .box extension. You can then pass this to your team mates (usb, network share, ftp etc.) and they can add it to their Vagrant installation and use it. Whenever they will do Vagrant up they will get fully provisioned VM in VBox with all the stuff you have packaged to it. Vagrant also gives you versioning capabilities. If properly configured whenever you will create new version of base box everybody who is using it will be notified and would be able to download and use new version of your box.
Hope I understood your problem correctly and this will help to solve it.

Comment: Yes I want to share the virtual machines I created with vagrant & shell provisioning without the other party having to do the provisioning part.

Comment: So if I export the machines as a base box, do they include the complete status of the machine (including the provisioning I did)? Second question - why is it not recommended? I understand from a shared development process point of view, but does it have other downsides?

Comment: When you package a base box it will contain current VM state. So if you provision all your required stuff save the state and then package the VM then all this will be packaged to the box. I am also learning Vagrant, I saw this on their site 'base boxes are generally not made by repackaging an existing Vagrant environment'. I think I did misinterpret as 'generally' does not really mean 'not recommended'!

Comment: So when I think of it now, after calling `vagrant up` you actually get fully functional VM in your VBox. Why not package it as a base box after the whole provisioning? I think you should give it a try!! I also found this which might be of help for you [click](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-create-a-vagrant-base-box-from-an-existing-one) it looks like Nicholas is doing exactly what you would like to do. Good luck !!

Comment: Great link. Thank you! Thats exactly what I've been looking for :)